# IntList, how to infer this picture

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

[image]
[image]

I could not understand this picture, I know tail means end of list, but like this:
L.tail.tail = N.tail.tail.tail.tail???
how could be that?

Answer (score 1):

Here tail means the next pointer. Now check the picture if it makes sense

I clearly see

```
         L.tail.tail or L.next.next is same as 
         N.tail.tail.tail.tail or N.next.next.next.next
```